# JS indexOf Always Returns -1

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I've got an array thats being built from a CSV file, the array builds just fine:

```
0: Array[80]
    0: "AM"
    1: "AX"
    2: "AR"
    3: "JR"
    4: "AC"
    5: "AF"
    etc...
```

I'm then trying to verify that a string taken from a text input appears at some point in the array.  The variable for the value of the text input is created, but the `indexOf()` always returns as `-1`.

I originally thought that maybe the variable being compared (`airlineCode`) was an object and that was the issue, but converting it to a string gives me the same results.  After that I thought maybe I could just circumvent the `indexOf()` by using `jQuery.inArray()`, also got the same result.  Code block looks like:

```
$("#employeeLoginButton").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/template/AirlineBlock/airlineCodes.csv",
        async: false,
        success: function (csvd) {
            data = $.csv2Array(csvd);
            var airlineCode = document.getElementById('airlineCode').value;
            airlineCode = String(airlineCode);
            var found = data.indexOf(airlineCode);
            console.log(airlineCode + found);

            if(found != -1) {
                sessionStorage.setItem("airlineVerified", true);
                window.location.href = "http://somesite.com";
            } else {
                alert("Nope")
            }
        },
        dataType: "text",
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you have both a `success` and `complete` function?

Comment: From what i can tell data is probably undefined unless you have it in the global scope somewhere.

Comment: Keep in mind that it is a case sensitive operation.

Comment: Also might want to check for white space in airlineCode

Comment: Maybe you should alert(airlineCode); right before your .indexOf also check if it has any white spaces, this can mess you up.

Comment: what @RocketHazmat is trying to say is that `complete` will run reguardless of the response type from the server, `success` will run if the response is ok and `fail` will run if the response is an error. So having both success and complete is redundant

Comment: @Buildersrejected: I'd suggest `console.log` over `alert`.

Comment: Thanks @dtanders, I had wondered the same thing, but no whitespace.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Combining `complete` into `success` gives the same result, but I see your point.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoshBurdick: Try to `console.log(data)` and `console.log(airlineCode)`.  One of those things isn't what you think it is.

Comment: For debugging purpose, could always try your own indexOf to loop through elements, make sure you have no junk in there.

Comment: Ahhh!  `data` was two-dimensional.  `var found = data[0].indexOf(airlineCode);` was the trick (the addition of the [0] index). @RocketHazmat

Comment: @JoshBurdick: Now that I look at the question again, that info was right there: `0: Array[80]`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I know... I completely overlooked it.